# Tanks! Unity currently trying to add a health pick up item

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("HealthPickUp"))
    {
        m_CurrentHealth += amount;
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        SetHealthUI ();
    }
    if (m_CurrentHealth <= 0f && !m_Dead)
    {
        OnDeath ();
    }
}
```

trying to get it that if the tank hits the pick up item it will gain 20 pointa but as of right now ive got no clue what to do

Comment: A bit more information is needed here. Can you include snapshots of the game objects that are colliding? Does you tank object have a rigidbody and collider? Does the health pickup have a collider set to trigger? and is the health pickup correctly tagged with HealthPickUp(no hidden spaces or upper/lower case differences)?

Comment: yes its a cube with a box collider with the trigger enabled it also has a rigdy body with gravity and kince enabled and it is correctly, id share more but im not sure how to edit on this site first post here

Comment: Where does the variable `amount` come from?

Comment: i added a slider to a cube a made it value 20 thinking that it would add 20 thinking back on it i guess that wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

To get collisions working in Unity, you need to do the following:

1. Attach a `Collider` component to **each** object you want to be part of the collision. This can be a `BoxCollider`, `SphereCollider`, etc. Whatever shape makes sense.
2. For trigger collisions (i.e. non-physics collisions), enable the `Is Trigger` value in the inspector on **each** collider component you created in step 1.
3. Attach a `RigidBody` component to the object you want to be colliding into other things. `RigidBody` components are expensive, and you don't want them all over the scene, so I would suggest you put it on your `Tank`. You may also have to turn on the `Is Kinematic` property, otherwise your `Tank` may behave improperly (it's hard to tell with such little information in your setup).
4. Attach a script to your `Tank` that has implemented the method `OnTriggerEnter`. An example is below.
5. (Optional, strongly recommended) I would suggest you create another script and attach it to your health pickup. I will demonstrate with an example below.
6. (Optional) You can use [layer based collisions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) to filter what kinds of collisions you detect to make it more efficient.

```C#
public class Tank : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Setup the initial health values in the editor.
    [SerializeField] private int _initialHealth = 100;
    [SerializeField] private int _maxHealth = 100;

    private int _health = -1;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _health = _initialHealth;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // You probably want to check this in Update, since you want the tank
        // to die as soon as it happens, not just when you pick up a piece of health.
        if (_health <= 0)
        {
            OnDeath();
        }
    }

    private void OnDeath()
    {
        // Your death logic.
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("HealthPickup"))
        {
            // Get the HealthPickup component and then add the amount to the tank's
            // health. This is more robust because you can now create HealthPickup
            // objects with a variable amount of health.
            HealthPickup healthPickup = other.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPickup>();
            if (healthPickup != null)
            {
                _health = Mathf.Clamp(_health + healthPickup.amount, 0, _maxHealth);
                healthPickup.OnPickup();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class HealthPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _amount = default;

    public int amount { get { return _amount; } }

    public void OnPickup()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

If you follow these steps, you should have collisions working and a flexible system for giving your `Tank` health pickups.